# ASP - Pick Images of Root Folder into Sub Folder

Tags: asp.net, html, image

I have had a look at this page

[HTML - pick images of Root Folder from Sub-Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655059/html-pick-images-of-root-folder-from-sub-folder)

This page contains an example for HTML images.
I have created a web control that represents footer of all the website pages. Now some pages are directly in the root and some are in another folder. In the web control I have to fix the

So without switching between ../ or ./ how can I determine the root of the website and then say something like root/images/abcd.jpg in the web control?

Comment: Use `~/` to get the application root.

Comment: This ~/ don't work at all neither in the main page (directly on the root) nor in the page inside a folder :(

Comment: @AzharKhorasany If Oded's suggestion doesn't work for you is because you need to make the `img` tag a server control by adding `runat="server"`. I explained this on my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make your `<img>` tag a server control by adding `runat="server"` you can simply do the following and it will always resolve the url correctly, regardless of where the user controls is referenced:

```
<img id="image" src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/images/abc.jpg")' />
```

The ResolveClientUrl method will automatically resolve the correct path starting off from the root of the app `(~/)`

Comment: This worked. <img src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/images/footer-imgs.jpg")%>" alt="" />. You put me in the right direction so I am marking yours an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
return url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(url.AbsolutePath, "") + "/";
```

To get the root.

Comment: Its an <img> tag. How will this code work in an html img tag?

Comment: if it's asp.net, can't you generate the path serverside?

Comment: I can, but I can't access the img id on the .aspx.cs file? The only other way is to use an ImageControl rather than <img>. Is that what you are asking me to do?

Comment: runat="server" for the img to access it's ID server side. But then if you want client side access, use TheID.ClientID