# How to set img "src" path so that root and nested pages can both find it...?

Tags: html, path, relative-path, src

I'm having trouble with an `<img>` element in a master page that I can't get to be reachable from both the home `default.aspx` page, and any nested page using the same `src` path.

For example, from the home page (located on the root), I'm able to display the image with:

```
<img src="Images/test.jpg">
```

But all pages located one level down, in a folder on the root, must use `src="../Images/test.jpg"` to display the image.

I have tried using `~` and other ways to get one path to work for both locations, but no luck yet.

This seems too easy, so I must be making this more difficult than it is... Feel free to enlighten me with any clues.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML - pick images of Root Folder from Sub-Folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655059/html-pick-images-of-root-folder-from-sub-folder)

Answer (score 23):

You can use

```
<img src="/Images/test.jpg">
```

in all the pages.

What ever be the page, image will be brought from url `www.yourdomian.com/Images/test.jpg`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that path has just the opposite effect, as no pages can display the image.... I tried many different path strings but still no luck. Hoping someone else has had this problem and can offer a solution...

Comment: After more research, I found that this issue seems to occur when using the built-in asp.net development server, but works ok when using WebMatrix to launch the site... not sure why this is, but I'm hoping all will be well when I upload to the host... will update once I have it up...

Comment: Update - everything works fine after uploading to the web server.

Comment: If the sample url is : http://website.com/myapp/default.aspx
;;
"./images/test.jpg" or "images/test.jpg" = http://website.com/myapp/images/test.jpg
;;
"/images/test.jpg" = http://website.com/images/test.jpg

Comment: just what I needed to know; working well for me now

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
@{    
   var src == Url.Content("~/images")+"/myImage.jpg";  
 }
```

Which also helps me to resolve the path `../` and `../../`
in jquery calendar image display in IE.

Comment: Follow the answer and apply @src to the image: <img src="@src" ... >

Answer (score -3):

In my case - c# asp.net mvc (before publishing) - I worked this workaround as also no src combination did work for me.

Somewhere on the beginning of my View

```
@{
  var path = Server.MapPath("~/Images");
  var src = path + "\\myImage.jpg";  
 }
```

Later (still on the View) for the image

```
<img src="@src" />
```

Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: this puts the exact path on the webpage, ie "C:\MyProject\" which you really don't want