# Image paths in Nuxt 3 + Vuetify

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have an image in my public folder (public/images/image.png) which is inside of a Vuetify v-img tag inside of a component (components/component.vue), with src="images/image.png". This works fine when displaying a page that is not nested in a folder, for example "pages/index.vue", but when I try display the same component in nested page "pages/something/index.vue" the component loads but not the image.

Comment: Use either absolute paths or aliases rather than relatives paths.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does adding a slash as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14894558/7088596) solve it?

Change `src="images/image.png"` to `src="/images/image.png"`

Comment: This should probably be a comment and/or duplicate flag.