# Differences in declaring your root directory in HTML

Tags: html, document-root

This has been bugging me for a long time so I need to ask the question.

What is the difference between `/` and `./`, is it just down to server settings?

For example, if we were looking for an images folder in the root directory we would write:

`<img src="/images">`

However, another server will only accept it as follows:

`<img src="./images">`

It's not a biggie, but in an ideal world I'd like to think I could transfer my sites to another server relatively easily without having to update minor details like these.

Of course, I can declare it in PHP and set it once in a config file, but it really is bugging me.  Why is there two methods for declaring the root?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To reference files relative to the current page, you can either write the path plainly without a prefix, or you can be explicit about it by prefixing with `./`. To reach files with paths relative to the root of your site, you prefix the path with `/`.

### Summary

`/` absolute path (full path to resource from root directory)
`./` relative path from current directory (equal to not specifying any folder prefix)
`../` relative path from parent directory
`../../` relative path from parent of parent

### Examples

```
Current URL               Resource path          Resolves to

/pages/home.html          ./picture.jpg          /pages/picture.jpg
/pages/home.html          ../img/picture.jpg     /img/picture.jpg
/pages/about/home.html    /img/picture.jpg       /img/picture.jpg
/pages/about/home.html    img/picture.jpg        /pages/about/img/picture.jpg
/home.html                img/picture.jpg        /img/picture.jpg
```

Comment: That makes absolute sense now you've pointed it out. Even makes me feel a little stupid! Though I'm still puzzled why some environments I work in won't accept `/` as the root.

Comment: Looking at the table you've added, I think you've cracked it. One place it doesn't work is in localhost where I have a number of sites. i.e. `localhost/site1`, `localhost/site2`, etc. So if I declare the root, rather than the current folder, it would go back to the root of localhost?

Comment: Yeah. If you're at `localhost/site1/page.html` and request `/js/jquery.js`, you're requesting `localhost/js/jquery.js`. You can get around this by binding your different sites to different ports, instead of having them in different folders on `localhost:80`.

Comment: Thanks stigok. I was thinking along these lines before but never managed to put my finger on it, and if you put `/` and `./` into Google it's very difficult to find an answer! (I have tried a few times.) When I'm at work I actually have my dev environment set up in my hosts file so have individual URLs (and root directories) allocated to each site. At home I use localhost, hence the differences. Every day's a school day.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same only if the source page (the one containing this HTML) is itself at the root of the domain.

In the general case, `./images` is equivalent to `images`.

Comment: Thanks dystroy. Following from stigok's answer this makes good sense too. I guess I've never experienced issues with declaring it as the current folder (e.g. `./images`) because almost all of the sites I build are based around an index page in the root which will pull in any other pages and content.

Comment: Just a tip : Prefer relative url. When both `images` and `/images` are valid, use the first one, as it will still be valid if you move your site down in the hierarchy of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with HTML, apart from the fact that URLs are used in HTML, too. This is defined in URL specifications. Briefly, ./ is relative to current base URL, and / is relative to the server root (technically, it refers to the server part of the base URL).