# Anchor and Img tags not finding PHP files or images

Tags: html, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, anchor, php-7.2

I guess **normally** what seems to work for everyone else (and what I want to do) is:

`<img src="/images/logo.png">` or `<img src="images/logo.png">`

Both of these options work locally (on the GCP App Engine).

When I use the command `gcloud app deploy` in the shell, my understanding is that it deploys the website. The code no longer works, the images are not found, and there are no errors reported (just little blue boxes where the images should be).

I have tried numerous variations, tried moving files into different folders, and read these two pages:

[Differences in declaring your root directory in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357693/differences-in-declaring-your-root-directory-in-html/15357705#15357705)

[Pick images of root folder from sub-folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655059/pick-images-of-root-folder-from-sub-folder)

My file structure can be described as:

```
HelloWorld
    images
        logo.png
    test
        tester.php
    trythis.php
    index.php
```

Where **HelloWorld**, **test** and **images** are folders.

I actually use the GCP Storage to host and store my images, the issue I am having is with hyperlinks, the anchor tag, and having a link from index.php to test.php. The link cannot find the file, so it is the same issue.

EDIT: complete code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
        <a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Click here</a>
        <a href="test/tester.php">Click here</a>
        <a href="/test/tester.php">Click here</a>
        <a href="trythis.php">Click here</a>
        <a href="/trythis.php">Click here</a>
        <br>
        <img src="images/logo.png">
        <img src="/images/logo.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

And my app.yaml:

```
runtime: php72
```

All works locally, none of it works on server.

Comment: Can you also include your app.yaml?

Comment: @JohnMichaelG have included now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup your app.yaml that include your directory folder and image type, so App Engine serves the files. Try to deploy with this app.yaml:

```
runtime: php72
handlers:
# Serve a directory as a static resource.
- url: /images
  static_dir: images
- url: /test
  static_dir: test

# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$
```

A line that begins with a pound (#) character is ignored or this is a comment. To know more about app.yaml, visit this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/config/appref#syntax).

For PHP files, to handle all request routing you will need to add a front controller. You can specify it in `index.php` link the example below or create a new file for front end controller but make sure that you will add this line `entrypoint: serve path/to/my/front/controller.php` in `app.yaml`.

**index.php:**

```
<?php
switch (@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']) {
    case '/':
        require 'index.php';
        break;
    case 'trythis.php':
        require 'trythis.php';
        break;
    case 'test/tester.php':
        require 'tester.php';
        break;
    default:
        http_response_code(404);
        exit('Not Found');
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PHP Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
        <a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Click here</a>
        <a href="test/tester.php">Click here</a>
        <a href="trythis.php">Click here</a>
        <br>
        <img src="images/logo.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I used your link to add the 'handlers' line, which then allowed me to deploy. Otherwise, this is a great answer for the images, but I can't get it to work for the php files - it downloads the file rather than displaying it. I also added this for the php files `- url: /test
    static_dir: test`

Comment: also tried to add `# Serve your app through a front controller at index.php or public/index.php.
- url: .*
  script: auto` but again no luck

Comment: Answer updated. The `url:* script: auto` is default. Is the updated answer did not work? Also what are you trying to do with php file?

Comment: Updated answer did not work. I just want to use it as the href within an anchor tag. At the moment I have this working: `<a href="https://www.google.co.uk">Google</a>` but when changing the href to a php file, it downloads the file instead of displaying it

Comment: The front end controller fixed it! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

in order to get to the images folder you have to first go up to the HelloWord folder.  Try the following:

```
<img src="../images/logo.png" >
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, this still isn't working for me.

Comment: Also, as the img tag is in the index.php file, wouldn't `../` take it up too high a level?

Comment: do you know how to use chrome developer tools? Right click on your web page and click on inspect. Then look for the network tab and click. Then refresh the web page in your browser (other window) and check on the network tab.  Locate the image and check its path

Comment: I am on safari so have checked safari dev tools and all I get are warnings - `[Warning] [blocked] The page at https://affable-visitor-292313.nw.r.appspot.com/ was not allowed to display insecure content from chrome-extension://__MSG_%40@extension_id__/data/ItalianPlateNo1Expanded-Regular.otf.
`

Comment: sorry, but I've always found apple products to be a nightmare to deal with.  download chrome and see what you get there

Comment: For your suggestion, I get the image name but it says 'An error occurred trying to load the resource`

Comment: try this in safari: 1. Open up Preferences by selecting "Preferences" from the "Safari" menu.

2. Click on the the "Security" (tab) icon near the top of the dialog.

3. Make sure that the "Ask before sending a non-secure form to a secure website" option is unchecked.

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your suggestion - I don't seem to have that option (am using Safari 13.0.4)

Comment: post your complete code so we can see what's actually going on

Comment: Have updated question with code - many thanks