# HTML img src outside the root folder

Tags: html, image

I am trying to refer to an image file which is outside source folder.
The current structure is

```
Images/img1.png

My Source Folder / Page-1 / index.html
```

From the index.html file, I want to refer to img1.png file.

I tried the following codes

```
<img src="../Images/img1.png">
<img src="../../Images/img1.png">
```

I don't want to hardcode the location because we have to deploy the code in production server and we are restricted to access the server and the details of the server. We only know that the server is Windows based server.

Can any one please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: second one should work, is your `Images` folder accessible by your server ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML - pick images of Root Folder from Sub-Folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655059/html-pick-images-of-root-folder-from-sub-folder)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to move **three** folders:

```
<img src="../../../Images/img1.png">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If `Images` and `My Source Folder` are the same level, only two `..` are sufficient

Comment: Two `..` is `My Source Folder` but `Images` is not inside it, it's a sibling folder, so you need to move one more... to the "root".