# Cannot access image in subfolders

Tags: html, image, permissions, twig, subdirectory

This may be a very simple question and I apologise for my naivety in advanced but I am having trouble accessing my images in subfolders.

I am developing on MAMP with Twig and PHP and here is my problem.

```
<img src="myimage.png" alt="">
```

Will successfully display 'myimage' on the site however when I try to access 'anotherimage' in a subfolder called 'pictures', I am unsuccessful.

```
<img src="pictures/anotherimage.png" alt="">
```

Doesn't want to work. I have tried:

```
<img src="./pictues/anotherimage.png" alt="">
```

as well as various other combinations but it wont display. I began to think this was a file permissions problem. The only way I know to change this was to go to the 'pictures' file and mke all permissions as 'read and write' via the finder in mac. This has not mde a difference.

Any ideas? Could it be a MAMP issue?

Comment: Have you tested via your Browser: http ://www.myhost.com/pictures/anotherimage.png ?

Comment: Just tried this jacouh and it could not access the image. 

I tried to access an image in the main folder with:
`http://localhost:8888/website/myimage.png` which works and displays the image but if I try `http://localhost:8888/website/pictures/anotherimage.png` it wont work? It is definitely in there as I can see it in the finder

Comment: I have the same problem as well. For some reason the same directory works but subdirectories don't work. Perhaps use webpack?

Comment: Turns out I mispeled the path. It seems that you also mispeled your path as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your folder organization of course is important in solving this. You might want to check the help and explanation here: [HTML - pick images of Root Folder from Sub-Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655059/html-pick-images-of-root-folder-from-sub-folder/3655065#3655065)

Comment: Hi Siaw_23 thanks for the response. Yes I have seen this and attempted a variety of examples such as '../' first or '/' first but none of them have worked. I have the same folder structure as this question (images/logo.png) and I am trying to access from index.html.