# How to link to file in root directory

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a website with `index.html` in the root folder, and a folder named `apples`. Inside `apples` I have another `index.html`. Currently I am attempting to use AngularJS to load the same navbar into both pages. However, when I tried linking to the Javascript file like so: `<script src="/controller.js">`, the JS file loads for the `index.html` in the root folder, but it refuses to load the file for the `index.html` in the `apples` folder. Does anyone know why? In the `apples` folder, it keeps linking to `apples//controller.js`.

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking server access logs to see what happens to your request? Maybe you've got a misbehaving rewrite that's preventing access to the js file and sending the request off to the homepage.

Comment: you should go one level up. So for index.html inside apples folder, you need to do `src="../controller.js"`

Comment: @KaushalNiraula: I want to copy and paste this line into any and all HTML pages I have, no matter how many folders it is inside (since it loads the same header for all of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running this on a server or just on your desktop? The path /controller.js should work if you're running from a web server but likely won't work if you're calling it locally.

Comment: I used `http-server` (on mac) and that resolved the issue. I didn't realize that running it from a server made that difference. Do you know why? And thanks for the help.

Comment: /controller.js is a valid absolute path on a server because the server knows you're referencing the root folder - /wwwroot/controller.js or /public_html/controller.js - but if you try to run the same code locally in a web browser, it's not a valid path on your desktop, so you need to use relative paths or, better still, have a web server running on your development machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="../js/controller.js"></script>
          __ ______ ________
          |    |       |
          |    |       |___ 3. Get the file named "logo.png"
          |    |
          |    |___ 2. Go inside "images/" subdirectory
          | 
          | 
          |____ 1. Go one level up
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655059/html-pick-images-of-root-folder-from-sub-folder)

Comment: This is a good answer, but I want to be able to copy and paste this one line of code into _any_ HTML page I have, no matter how many folders it is inside (it loads the same header for all of them). That's why I prefer the `/` method over the `../` method.