# How to set source path in Html?

Tags: html

I want to include a image in common
-componets
-header
-header.html   from another directory js_src
-assets
-images
-phot.svg
How to give path in src attribute could any one please Help me?

Comment: This question is difficult to answer without the exact directory setup for your project and the frameworks you're using (if any). Could you provide those details or at least the frameworks?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655059/pick-images-of-root-folder-from-sub-folder 
This might helps you.